# Thread safety of enum constants used for connecting to different databases

Tags: java, multithreading, enums, thread-safety

Should getConnection() inside Enum be synchronized?

Which one is thread safe?

First:

```
public enum DBConnection {

POSTGRESQL("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb", "vagrant", "vagrant"),
MYSQL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "vagrant", "vagrant");

DBConnection(String host, String user, String password) {

    this.host = host;
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;
}

private final String host;
private final String user;
private final String password;

private Connection connection;

public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

    if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, password);
    }

    return connection;
}}
```

or second, synchronized call and volatile variable:

```
private volatile Connection connection;

public synchronized Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

    if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, password);
    }

    return connection;
}
```

Calling connection, for instance:

```
      try (Connection connection = DBConnection.POSTGRESQL.getConnection()) {
       // Prepared statement etc
        }
    } catch (SQLException ignored) {}
```

Comment: I think I would rather return a new connection each time.

Comment: @Axel,Yea, I know, but this example is from Pluralsite course. The author treats connection as above.

Answer (score 2):

> Which one is thread safe?

The first option is not *thread-safe* because you have a *check-then-act* situation that can result in a race condition. The second option is *thread safe* but the use of `volatile` is redundant if you are synchronizing the entire `getConnection` method.

That said, you are better off using a *conneciton pool* rather than a *Singleton* DB connection.

Comment: For anyone wondering why the code is thread-safe or not thread-safe, the key point to understand is that each `enum` constant is an instance of the `enum`. Calling a method that changes the state of on an `enum` constant (instance) from multiple threads requires most of the thread-safety guarantees as the ones required for objects of `class` types.